# python datetime does not update on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, datetime, ubuntu, gunicorn

I am having the following code on ubuntu as part of a django applicaiton that is deployed using gunicorn.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
day = now.day
start = now.replace(hour=14,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
end = now.replace(hour=16,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
day1 = datetime.datetime(year, month, day)
day1 = day1.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
if day1.weekday() != 0:
    # Make day1 == Weekday 0 == Monday
    day1 = day1 - timedelta(days=day1.weekday())
day2 = day1 + timedelta(days=1)
day3 = day1 + timedelta(days=2)
day4 = day1 + timedelta(days=3)
day5 = day1 + timedelta(days=4)
day6 = day1 + timedelta(days=5)
day7 = day1 + timedelta(days=6)
day8 = day1 + timedelta(days=7)
day9 = day1 + timedelta(days=8)
day10 = day1 + timedelta(days=9)
```

Meaning that on Monday automatically `day1` should be reset to the next week, e.g. from Mo, 21th June to Mo, 28th June. But it is not happening and I always have to restart my server/gunicorn process... any ideas on how to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: You don't move `day1` on to the next week, you just set it to the start of the current week.

Comment: yes, but if `day1`is a monday then the if is not applied, or what do you mean @Kemp?

Comment: That's what the if statement does, literally. `if day1.weekday() != 0`, where 0 is Monday, says don't run it if the current weekday is Monday.

Comment: Where is the code located, in a class, function or a mdoule?

Comment: @Kemp yes you are right, but the rest of the code is still executed and `day1` is still defined... so I still not understand this issue and how to fix it..

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby the code is in a script that is run without dependencies...

Comment: Where does this code exist?

Comment: You just need an `else` for that `if` (which will execute only on monday) that moves the date on by a week.